# Não consigo editar arquivos css

Tags: php, css

Antes eu não utilizava o PHP utilizava somente o HTML e CSS para desenvolver o projeto mas surgiu a necessidade do PHP, logo tive que utilizar também o XAMPP, mas acontece que eu modifiquei os arquivos HTML para PHP e agora não consigo mais editar meus arquivos CSS.

Consigo editar os arquivos que mudei para PHP mas para editar os arquivos CSS que estão linkados com o PHP não sofre alteração a página, chego a mudar o que quero mas não sofre efeito.

Alguém poderia mostrar alguma solução? Pois antes quando não utilizava o PHP conseguia editar normalmente, agora não mas.

Comment: Se for mesmo o cache você pode tentar dar um CTRL + F5 para tentar limpa-lo

Comment: Talvez seja cache, tentou outro navegador ou tentou dar um 'crtl + alt + r' no crhome para limpar o cache da página.

Comment: Quando fui no código fonte dá página e depois no do CSS, mesmo eu mudando com o meu editor lá mostra como se eu não tivesse editado.

Comment: Antes eu estava atualizando a página com apenas o F5, mas quando apertei junto do CTRL foi, por que isso ocorre ?

Comment: Provavelmente há 2 arquivos .CSS e a chamada do teu arquivo está indicando algum css que não é o que está editando.
Confira o seu :

    <link href="css/arquivo.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Sim eu estou utilizando um arquivo CSS para cada página, isso está errado ?

Comment: Confira o endereço novamente. Vá manualmente até ele e abra o arquivo css para certificar que está EDITANDO o cara certo. Sobre cache e arquivos temporários, eu já tive problemas em celulares, o navegador não atualizava, foi preciso atualizar manualmente, exceções extremas! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute o site no seu navegador e abra o código fonte, e tente acessar o arquivo CSS linkado. Se ele não existir, arrume o link!

Alguns servidores precisam de uma barra no inicio do arquivo: /

A barra indica pasta raiz. Exemplo: '/css/arquivo.css'

Se ele estiver certo, aperte CTRL+5, pode ser que você esteja editando ele, porém existe cache no navegador.